# How to convert std::result_of to decltype in a template argument

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14, decltype

At CppCon 2015, S. Lavavej from Microsoft [said](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zt7ThwVfap0#t=17m15s) to avoid using `result_of`. But I have a situation in which I can't seem to be able to find a proper alternative.

Consider the following code. Is there any way to change `std::result_of<F()>::type` to use `decltype` instead?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <future>
#include <type_traits>

template<typename T>
struct NopErrCB
{
  constexpr T operator() () const { return T(); }
};

template <typename Func, typename ErrCB>
struct SafeTaskWrapper {
  Func f;
  ErrCB errCB;

  template <typename... T>
  auto operator()(T&&... args) -> decltype(f(args...)) {
    try
    {
      return f(std::forward<T>(args)...);
    }
    catch (...)
    {
      return errCB();
    }
  }

};
//                                   vvv OVER HERE  vvv
template <typename F>
SafeTaskWrapper<F, NopErrCB<typename std::result_of<F()>::type>> make_safe_task(F&& f) {
  return { std::forward<F>(f) };
}

template <typename F, typename ErrCB>
SafeTaskWrapper<F, ErrCB> make_safe_task(F&& f, ErrCB&& cb) {
  return { std::forward<F>(f), std::forward<ErrCB>(cb) };
}

int main() {
  auto futA = std::async(std::launch::async, make_safe_task([] { throw "A"; return 1; }));
  auto futB = std::async(std::launch::async, make_safe_task([] { throw "B"; return 1; }, [] { return 2; }));
  auto futC = std::async(std::launch::async, make_safe_task([] { throw "C"; }));
  std::cout << futA.get() << std::endl;
  std::cout << futB.get() << std::endl;
  futC.get();
}
```

<sub>PS. Please don't mind the purpose of the SafeTaskWrapper. I know a future already handles C++ exceptions. This is just a demo, the actual code is for handling Windows SEH exceptions, but that doesn't matter for this question.</sub>

Comment: `decltype(std::declval<F>()())` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might use

```
decltype(std::declval<F>()())
```

instead of

```
typename std::result_of<F()>::type
```

which are similar, but have subtle differences

Comment: The only differences in C++14 have to do with pointers to member functions or pointers to members.  There are no other differences, and no SFINAE differences beyond them.  So, what is the point of this change?

Answer (score 4):

Yes, your use of `result_of` here causes a bug.  And yes, there is a way to write your code without `result_of` that clears the bug.  And we can do this without constructing an equivalently buggy `decltype` replacement.

First, note your `result_of` code has a bug.

```
struct evil {
  template<class...Args>
  int operator()(Args&&)&&{return 0;}
  template<class...Args>
  std::string operator()(Args&&)const&{return "hello";}
};
```

Pass an `evil{}` to your code, and it will fail to compile.  That is because you evaluated `f` in `SafeTaskWrapper` in an lvalue context, while you calculated `result_of` in an rvalue context.

This is exactly the kind of error that S.T.L. was talking about.

Now, `std::result_of_t<F(Args...)>` is basically<sup>1</sup> equivalent to `decltype( std::declval<F>()( std::declval<Args>()... ) )`, or in this case `decltype( std::declval<F>()())`.  Replacing `result_of_t` with `decltype` in this sense is utterly useless.

What I'd do here is I'd change the rest of your code.

```
struct anything_really {
  template<class T> operator T() const { return {}; }
};
struct return_anything {
  anything_really operator()() const { return {}; }
};
```

this replaces your `errCB` type.  Note that it isn't a template type.

Next, we have to handle the "don't return into void" problem.  This does it:

```
template<class R>
struct smart_invoke {
  template<class F>
  R operator()(F&& f)const {
    return std::forward<F>(f)();
  }
};
template<>
struct smart_invoke<void> {
  template<class F>
  void operator()(F&& f)const {
    std::forward<F>(f)();
  }
};
```

Which gives us our final solution:

```
template <typename Func, typename ErrCB=return_anything>
struct SafeTaskWrapper {
  Func f;
  ErrCB errCB;

  template <class... Ts>
  decltype(auto) operator()(Ts&&... args) {
    try {
      return f(std::forward<T>(args)...);
    } catch (...) {
      using R=decltype( f( std::forward<T>(args)... ) );
      return smart_invoke<R>{}(errCB);
    }
  }
};
```

Now our factory functions.  I could keep two, but I'm lazy.

```
template <class ErrCB=return_anything, class F>
SafeTaskWrapper<F, ErrCB> make_safe_task(F&& f, ErrCB&& cb = {}) {
  return { std::forward<F>(f), std::forward<ErrCB>(cb) };
}
```

I also swapped the template argument order, so you can pass in a different default-constructible `ErrCB` and not bother passing in a value while I was at it.

And `result_of_t` has been eliminated.

Also your trailing return decltype had an error in it.  It should be *exactly* the same as the (key) return statement, not similar.

---

<sup>1</sup> There are exceptions if `F` is a member function pointer or member or the like, but your code won't work in those cases anyhow.  In C++17, you'll want to call `std::invoke` in your `operator()` and in the `decltype` return type clause as well.  The other changes remain correct, and because we avoid deducing the return type in two spots, they remain unchanged.

Comment: Thanks for the info. Nice idea with a functor that returns whatever type you expect. But I get: `error C2562: '... operator (): 'void' function returning a value` at the line where I create `futC` (void lambda).

Comment: @RustyX fixed: I wrote `smart_invoke` that knows to discard return values if it is expected to return `void`.  Note you would have had the same problem if someone manually passed an `errCB` that did not return `void` and an `f` that did return void.

Comment: owww, that `smart_invoke` really throws a wrench into the solution :) And I think you're missing a `template<>` in front of the `<void>` specialization.

Answer (score 2):

That's where `std::result_of` is used. I think that is enough.

If you want shorter and more readable code, consider using `std::result_of_t`, which is added since C++14.

```
//NopErrCB<typename std::result_of<F()>::type>
NopErrCB<std::result_of_t<F()>> // equal
```

Answer (score 1):

The direct translation would be:

```
template <typename F>
SafeTaskWrapper<F, NopErrCB<decltype(std::declval<F>()())>> make_safe_task(F&& f) {
  return { std::forward<F>(f) };
}
```

Which seems no clearer to me.